# Convert HH:mm into Moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

So I have some time data such as follows:

```
10:45 PM
11:35 PM
12:06 AM
01:34 AM
```

All of these times are in `America/Los_Angeles` and each time is guaranteed to be after `09:00 PM` in today in that timezone. So that times which are past midnight take place tomorrow.

Is there an elegant way to convert these times from the current format into `moment.js` objects with the times pinned to the appropriate day.

Comment: Do you need these represented to `America/Los_Angeles` even if the user is running from a different time zone?  Or is working in the local time zone good enough?

Answer (score 41):

```
moment('09:00','h:mm a').format('h:mm a');
```

Answer (score 21):

Found in moment.js doc:

```
moment('10:45 PM', 'HH:mm a')
```

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/

Comment: No, this will not work, since a time of '01:00 AM' will be mapped to the current rather than the following day.

Comment: this does not answer the question since it is not using America/Los_Angeles timezone asked in the question

Answer (score 15):

```
function getMomentFromTimeString(str) {
  var t = moment(str, 'HH:mm A');
  // Now t is a moment.js object of today's date at the time given in str

  if (t.get('hour') < 22) // If it's before 9 pm
    t.add('d', 1); // Add 1 day, so that t is tomorrow's date at the same time

  return t;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `tz()` method:

```
var date = moment().tz("America/Los_Angeles").startOf('day');
date.hour(22);
date.minutes(45);
```

Then convert it to local time:

```
date.local().toDate();
```