# convert string time to moment in javascript

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I would like to know is it possible to convert string `time` to moment in javascript.
I am using moment.js

```
var str="11:00" // convert this to moment()
```

I tried

```
var result = moment(str); //not working
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert HH:mm into Moment.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23282547/convert-hhmm-into-moment-js)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `format` method:

```
moment('11:00','h:mm a').format('h:mm a');
```

[More info can be read here.](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/)

Comment: I don't understand the downvote, as it fits the described problem perfectly. Anyways.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it as follows

```
moment(str, 'h:mm a')
```

for more information please refer https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/